# How to create a websocket wrapper using python

Tags: python, api, websocket

I'm currently working on my project to create a python wrapper for the gemini api (https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/). I'm in the process of working on the order events websocket (https://docs.gemini.com/websocket-api/#order-events) and having difficulty using the websocket client for python. This is how my code right now:

```
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import time
from websocket import create_connection
import requests

public_key = 'asdfkjdfdfk'
private_key = 'asdfkjdfdfk'
url = "https://api.sandbox.gemini.com/v1/order/status"


def header(method, payload=None):
    if payload is None:
        payload = {}
    payload['request'] = method
    payload['nonce'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
    payload['order_id'] = '86499545'
    b64_payload = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8'))
    signature = hmac.new(private_key.encode('utf-8'), b64_payload, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()

    headers = {
        'X-GEMINI-APIKEY': public_key,
        'X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD': b64_payload,
        'X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE': signature,
    }
    return headers


r = requests.post(url, headers=header('/v1/order/status'))
print(r.json())

ws = create_connection("wss://api.sandbox.gemini.com/v1/order/events",
                       header=header('/v1/order/events'))
```

when i run script i get the following error :

```
{'order_id': '86499545', 'id': '86499545', 'symbol': 'btcusd', 'exchange': 'gemini', 'avg_execution_price': '0.00', 'side': 'buy', 'type': 'exchange limit', 'timestamp': '1511299791', 'timestampms': 1511299791519, 'is_live': False, 'is_cancelled': True, 'is_hidden': False, 'was_forced': False, 'executed_amount': '0', 'remaining_amount': '0.1', 'options': ['maker-or-cancel'], 'price': '7900.00', 'original_amount': '0.1'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uzman\Documents\Python\Gemini- Python API Wrapper\gemini\testing.py", line 35, in <module>
    header=header('/v1/status/order'))
  File "C:\Users\uzman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 487, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "C:\Users\uzman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 214, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "C:\Users\uzman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 63, in handshake
    headers, key = _get_handshake_headers(resource, hostname, port, options)
  File "C:\Users\uzman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 110, in _get_handshake_headers
    headers.extend(header)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bytes found
[Finished in 1.5s]
```

As you can see from the first request, the api successfully allows us to create an order meaning the verification works correctly. However, the problem seems to be with the `websocket` module. I can't seem to figure out how to successfully create the web socket connection. I know i encoded the `b64_payload` and `signature` using `utf8` encoding but that's what the gemini api requires you to do and I can't change that because if i do then the first request doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your payload should be passed to hmac.new() as ASCII/binary (not utf-8). You are still required to encode the payload in utf-8 when placing it in the header though.